# How to use Excel INDIRECT return dynamic range

Tags: excel-formula

I use formula as below to get what I need:

```
=$G467-INDIRECT(ADDRESS(LOOKUP(2,1/($J$1:$J466=$J467),ROW($J$1:$J466)),7))
```

I try to use formula as below for dynamic range

```
=$G467-INDIRECT(ADDRESS(LOOKUP(2,1/(INDIRECT("$J$1:$J"&(ROW()-1),1)=$J467),ROW(INDIRECT("$J$1:$J"&(ROW()-1),1))),7))
```

But I got N/A, does anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your formulae are valid, but inefficient (due to the use of the volatile `INDIRECT()` function).

A more efficient version of your first formula would be

```
=$G467-INDEX($G$1:$G$466,MAX(($J$1:$J466=$J467)*ROW($J$1:$J466)))
```

(this will have to be entered as an [array formula](https://exceljet.net/glossary/array-formula) if you aren't using Excel 2021/Microsoft 365)

and a more efficient (albeit longer) version of your second formula would be

```
=$G467-INDEX($G$1:INDEX($G1:$G466,ROW()-1),MAX(($J$1:INDEX($J1:$J466,ROW()-1)=$J$467)*ROW($J$1:INDEX($J1:$J466,ROW()-1))))
```

(if you had to enter the first formula as an array formula then you will also have to enter this one in the same way)

That your second formula returned `#N/A` is either because of your data, or because of the cell where you entered the formula: if you enter your second formula in a cell on row 467 then it should produce the same result as your first formula.